# отловить ошибку в приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, исключения

всем привет.
есть приложение, которое падает по необработанному исключению на удаленной машине (Win 10, x64, появляется окно об ошибке, с кнопкой завершить приложение). проблема лишь в том, что не понятно какому. есть только уведомление в журнале ошибок, без конкретики:

```
Имя сбойного приложения: xxl.exe, версия: 2020.7.31.1615, метка времени: 0x5f285803
Имя сбойного модуля: ntdll.dll, версия: 10.0.14393.2969, метка времени: 0x5ccd12bb
Код исключения: 0xc0000374
Смещение ошибки: 0x000d9741
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x1ef4
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d669c4fd434560
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\xxl.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Идентификатор отчета: 410ee762-d925-48e0-91d8-48a42ea33be8
Полное имя сбойного пакета: 
Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:
```

Через удаленную отладку, студия исключение не перехватывает.
Использовал DebugTools, снимал дамп в момент ошибки, но анализатор показывает то же самое, что и в журнале ошибок.

Подписался на все виды необработанных исключений в лог:

```
CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
Dispatcher.UnhandledException
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
```

Но увы - ничего не логируется.

Был бы признателен за советы. Реально с такой красотой сталкиваюсь впервые.

Comment: Оно при старте падает? Вы там с мс офисом ничего в приложении не делаете?

Comment: Нет. Падает при работе. С офисом не работаю.

Comment: На какой то конкретной операции? Или рандомно?

Comment: Абсолютно рандомно. И никак не перехватить его.

Comment: у вас только одна машина на win10? На ней все последние обновления установлены? Вообще, по коду ошибки и по названию ntdll.dll много чего гуглится.

Comment: `есть приложение` Приложение ваше? Что приложение делает? Исходные коды есть? Дополнительные библиотеки или API операционной системы используется?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, мое. корпоративный софт, исходный код есть, намешано там многое. другое дело, что не могу отловить саму ошибку. выходит, что только опытным путем придется вычислять узкое место. думал может есть еще какие нибудь инструменты.

Comment: @tym32167, на нескольких удаленных (все win10) машинах тестил, везде валится. Разработку веду под win7, на ней все ок. По коду гуглил, результат - грубо говоря повреждение динамической кучи. Согласитесь не очень информативно. Кто и что вредит - не известно. Пока неизвестно.

Comment: @mrbrooks Может имеет смысл разработку перенести на win10, если все клиенты на них. Если у вас тоже будет валиться, то может и ошибку поймаете.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, видимо так и придется сделать. Иначе не отловить причину. Хотя с другой стороны, удаленный отладчик то ничего не ловит. В общем начинаю танец с бубном.

Comment: Чтобы проверить логирвоание, можно для отладки поборосать исключение вручную с помощью `throw` в разных частях кода.

Comment: все таки поплясав с бубном, вопрос решил. косяк был в зоопарке  - wpf + prism + unity. Я в базовой модели-представлении каким то лешим определил интерфейс связанный с COM Interop, хотя по факту он нужен в одной мод. представлении. выходило что он наследовался во многих представлениях, что приводило в некое смятение динамическую кучу и возможно сборщика, который притомился считать ссылки. В общем решилось все банальным разрешением данного интерфейса в нужной модели-представлении и все стало ок. однако. что бы это допетрить потребовались сутки. старею. Однако хочется гламура и инструментов.